# how to attach click function to multiple divs without ID

Tags: javascript, css, class

I have a fade in function im trying to understand better. It works fine when I set up the

My question is if I have 8 links that already have the separate ID and class names how can I attach this function to each clickable link?

Is there a function to getElementbyClass or something and then just add the class to all my links?

here is my javascript:

```
var done = true,
    fading_div = document.getElementById('fading_div'),
    fade_in_button = document.getElementById('fade_in'),
    fade_out_button = document.getElementById('fade_out');

function function_opacity(opacity_value) {
    fading_div.style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    fading_div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity_value + ')';
}

function function_fade_out(opacity_value) {
    function_opacity(opacity_value);
    if (opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'none';
        done = true;
    }
}

function function_fade_in(opacity_value) {
    function_opacity(opacity_value);
    if (opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (opacity_value == 100) {
        done = true;
    }
}
// fade in button
fade_in_button.onclick = function () {
    if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '1') {
        done = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout((function (x) {
                return function () {
                    function_fade_in(x)
                };
            })(i), i * 10);
        }
    }
};
// fade out button
fade_out_button.onclick = function () {
    if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '0') {
        done = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout((function (x) {
                return function () {
                    function_fade_out(x)
                };
            })(100 - i), i * 10);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: There ***is*** a [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) method.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()`, `.querySelectorAll()`, or [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) are going to be your friends here.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#each
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#fade_in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the answer from BLiu1:

```
var fadeDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('fade');
for (var i=0, i<fadeDivs.length, i++){
// do stuff to all fade-divs by accessing them with "fadeDivs[i].something"
}
```

Comment: so just add this to my current code and add a clas fade to all my divs?

Comment: the original selector is fade_in does that not make a difference?

Comment: Yes, you just write this wherever you want to do something to your divs and at the point where I wrote the comment, you insert the code that you want to apply to every div. To refer to the divs, use "fadeDivs[i].(your code)". That way, you can access the div in the fadeDivs array, that has the index = 'i'. How you call your class is up to you, just be consistent with it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a javascript library like jQuery to manage this.  They have some extensive, very easy to use "selectors" that allow you to easily get access to elements in the DOM and animate them with things like "fade ins" and "slides", etc.  If you need more animations there are tons of plugins available for this.  It also helps to deal with browser compatibility challenges too.

If you want to rely on pure JavaScript, you can use the document.getElementsByClassName() function defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), but that function is only defined in IE9 and above as well as Safari, Chrome, FF, and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, there is a `getElementsByClassName()` method. Here is how you would use it.

```
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("fade").length; i++ ){
    /*apply fade in function*/
}
```

I'm not sure whether `getElementsByClassName()` can detect one class name at a time. You might need regex for that.

Comment: would you mind adding my code to your answer to show me exactly how to use this.